# Bad Request Invalid Header JSONType Mismatch

Tags: android

Getting this response every time when i try to hit api use in my app.That is response which i get during api hit.Content type that i put in header is.application/json; charset=utf-8 but in respnose their is error and display ascii characters.Need help to solve it.

```
> <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML
> 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad     Request</TITLE> <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type"
> Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD> <BODY><h2>Bad Request -
> Invalid Header</h2> <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request has an invalid
> header name.</p> </BODY></HTML>
```

This is class where i put headers..

> ```
> public class CustomJSONStringRequest extends StringRequest {
> public CustomJSONStringRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener,
>                                Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
>     super(method, url, listener, errorListener);
> }
> @Override
> public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
>     HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
>     headers.put("Cache-Control","no-cache");
>     headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
>     headers.put("Authorization", ".....");
>     headers.put("X-API-KEY", "......");
>     return headers;
> } }
> ```

Comment: Hi, the message seems pretty clear, you have an invalid header name. Can you provide a list of your headers ?

Comment: Yes You can check again my post problem is with content type

Comment: it also depends on what are all headers API is accepting. ie. may be you are missing one or more headers. and there are other possibilities of getting BadRequest error to know that find out with API code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try putting "Accept" instead of "Content-Type"

Comment: Thank you so much Accept is working at place of Content-Type.

Comment: oh my GOD you have solved my issue after having 24 hour hard work

Comment: You are welcome, don't hesitate to up vote the answer, it might be useful to other devs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly provide header name upon calling